# two projects, one wcf service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

hey everyone.
ok, a  little background to the project... I've released a program to a couple clients that use a WCF service for them to connect to our servers in the office. Being that i used the clickOnce setup utility in VS2010, when i am doing testing on a VM i publish to a different spot on the server as to not give untested code to clients. However, the WCF service only gets published to one place for both versions (development and release).

What i'm working on now requires a change to the WCF service as a couple additional things get transferred between client and server. If I publish the modified WCF, will it affect the current clients, or will i be able to test my development version with no worries?  I'm afraid i already know that the answer will be, yes it will affect them.

thanks!
dave k.

Comment: Do you have multiple end points.  What determines whether or not the client is using the test or prod version of the service.

Comment: If you need to test new stuff, I would strongly suggest publishing it to a separate server/service URL until you've stabilized your code, and possibly also tested against an "old" client to be sure of any potential breaking changes you might introduce...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Isolation of test, dev and production:**
Whenever you need to test something or put it in production, you need a separate environment. So you need a separate machine to develop and do local testing, another to test the checked-in code (for use by a tester, a customer etc.), and another to run the production code -- at the very least.

If your service interacts with other software, especially with software that gets updated a lot, this is an important way to make sure that you don't introduce side-effects and that what you build will be compatible with what is running on your production server.

So: isolate and make your test environment a "clone" of your production environment.

**Two versions in parallel:**
If you update your own code for customer X, you can still host a previous version of your production code for customer Y on another (virtual?) server. Customer Y can then choose when to switch to your new version, after which you can take the old code out of production.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a seperate VM for your test environment.